# How to design a "two column button" in Ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

What I would like to achieve is this:

[image]

Surely, I went through the [button](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#buttons) documentation, but it seems nothing similar is there. So, I would appreciate some pointing in the right direction (codepen with a basic example would be most awesome).

So, ideally, this would be one button tag where I would be able to pass two variables (one which would appear on the left and one on the right). This does smell like a job for a Angular directive, though I haven't fiddled with it too much just yet so a friendly nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing in the end was this: I created a `div` with a class `button` and then inside it I created additional two `div`'s with custom classes.

The code below:

```css
.leftButtonSide {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    color: #000;
}

.rightButtonSide {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="d in data" class="button button-positive-outline">
    <div class="leftButtonSide">2</div>
    <div class="rightButtonSide">2,00</div>
</div>
```

True, for the exact same look you would have to play a bit with CSS. I ended up with this in the end:

[image]

Hope this helps someone too!

Answer (score 0):

There is something similar to this in their documentation
http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#button-bar

```
<div class="button-bar">
  <a class="button">First</a>
  <a class="button">Second</a>
</div>
```